# Rails 4 Turbolinks Problems With History API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, html5-history

I am trying to disable turbolinks on a specific page which uses ajax tabs.

The reason for that is Turbolinks creates an initial **History.state** that creates problems with the **History API** in the browser.

```
{"turbolinks":true,"url":"my_current_url"}
```

[image]

The actions are the following (graph above)

1. Initial page loaded (with the turbolinks history state)
2. Tab 2 clicked, pushed state
3. Tab 3 clicked, pushed state
4. Back button pressed in the browser, $.getScript called in the popState event to fetch only the Tab 2 without reloading the entire page
5. Back button clicked again. Here $.getScript is called again, but also the turbolinks state which trigger a full turbolink request for the all body.

I am trying to get rid of that turbolinks request that is triggered in the popState event.
I tried disabling turbolinks on this specific page with

```
<body data-no-turbolink="true">
```

But that does not work for me.

Any idea how to disable turbolinks from adding this history state on the first load of the page?